# How to fix a library not found error on Xcode

Tags: xcode

I use Xcode 11.3.1.

I receive an Xcode project from a coworker that is using Xcode 12.4.

I open the project and try to build it.

I receive the following error:

```
Library not found for ISO8601DateFormatterValueTransformer
```

Inside Xcode there are some details:

```
ld: warning: directory not found for option '-L/Users/catalina/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/CDA-chskvgcrkhxpgnghuarozjoeymbq/Build/Products/Debug-iphonesimulator/ISO8601DateFormatterValueTransformer'
ld: warning: directory not found for option '-L/Users/catalina/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/CDA-chskvgcrkhxpgnghuarozjoeymbq/Build/Products/Debug-iphonesimulator/RKValueTransformers'
ld: warning: directory not found for option '-L/Users/catalina/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/CDA-chskvgcrkhxpgnghuarozjoeymbq/Build/Products/Debug-iphonesimulator/RestKit'
ld: warning: directory not found for option '-L/Users/catalina/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/CDA-chskvgcrkhxpgnghuarozjoeymbq/Build/Products/Debug-iphonesimulator/SOCKit'
ld: warning: directory not found for option '-L/Users/catalina/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/CDA-chskvgcrkhxpgnghuarozjoeymbq/Build/Products/Debug-iphonesimulator/TransitionKit'
ld: warning: directory not found for option '-L/Users/catalina/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/CDA-chskvgcrkhxpgnghuarozjoeymbq/Build/Products/Debug-iphonesimulator/ZBarSDK'
ld: library not found for -lISO8601DateFormatterValueTransformer
clang: error: linker command failed with exit code 1 (use -v to see invocation)
```

My coworker said to me to delete the Pods folder and run the `pod install` command. After running the command some libraries are installed on the project.
But when I try to build the project, it fails.

This problem could be related to my Xcode version? I mean, I was trying to compile a project using an old version of Xcode

Or

this is a problem related to not importing correctly the Library?

Answer (score -2, accepted):

I find out what was causing the problem.

I open the xcproject file. The correct file to open the project is the xcworkspace file.

The problem is fixed now.